# Configure push notification with parse-server

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, parse-server

Hei, i'm trying to send push notification to android app that use parse-server.
My environment is local, and i'm using ubuntu 16.04.

If i try to send push by curl with this:

```
  curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: myMasterKey" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "channels": [""],
    "data": {
        "alert": "Hello!"
      }
    }' \
https://localhost:1337/parse/push
```

i get the error: "missing push configuration"

What configurations should i set? and where?

I'm using Titanium/Alloy to develope the app. I tryed to send push notification directly from the app with:

```
Parse.Push.send({
  where: {
        user: {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "_User",
            objectId: userId
        }
  },
  data: {
    alert: "new notification!",
  }
}, {
  useMasterKey: true,
  success: function() {
    console.log("Successfull");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("Some error occurred");
  }
});
```

but i got the error "Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided". So i inizialized parse-server with `Parse.initialize(applicationId, javaScriptKey, masterKey)` getting still the same error.

Could you help me? It is important :(

Other little question: to create a cloud function with local parse-server on ubuntu, where should i put my main.js file? i have the directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server`.

If you can answer at least one of this questions, please do! Thanks

Regards, Luca

Comment: "missing push configuration": This might be because you didn't set push configuration like describe here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#2-configure-parse-server

Comment: did u manage to figure out the problem?, because I am stuck on the same kinda problem